# A proof regarding connected components of a graph

Tags: graph-theory, inequality

Been struggling with this home-work question for some days now. Will appreciate an explanation.

Let $c(G)$ denote the amount of connected components in a graph $G$.

a. prove that $\forall e\in E: c(G) \leq c(G-e) \leq c(G)+1$

b. show that there is a graph $G$ with a vertex $v$ such that $c(G-v) \geq c(G)+1$

I'm kinda new to this all graph-theory subject so I so kinda lost on how to get started as well.
Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Hint for (b): You need a graph in which there are several (at least two) pairs of vertices which are connected by one path each, all the paths passing through the same vertex $v$. For example, $a\cdots v \cdots b$, $a \cdots v \cdots c$, $b \cdots v\cdots c$, with those being the only paths between $a$ and $b$, $a$ and $c$, and $b$ and $c$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $e=\{a, b\}$ is in connected component $A$ of $G$. you need to show that:

1. Connected components of $G$ other than $A$ will remain connected components of $G-e$.
2. Every vertex in $A$ can be joint to either $a$ or $b$ using edges in $A - e$. so each vertex of $A - e$ will be in either $a$'s or $b$'s respective connected component.

for part b of your question, think of a star!

Comment: Part (b) is extremely easy, don't give it away like that!

Comment: @M.Vinay I don't know what exactly I'm supposed to "give away" in these situations. If someone can not prove these obvious statements, maybe he or she has trouble thinking in Graph theory terms, that is probably because of poor education, and these kind of answers could really help them to become more familiar with the topic and to have better initiative. However If there is a strict regulation against this, please inform me.

Comment: Oh, I don't really know about the regulations either, but giving away dead easy answers is generally frowned upon, from what I've seen. I just thought you could give some hints for it (like I've done in my comment) and see if they get the answer. No worries!

Comment: concerning a, I understand the logic, but can't seem to find the formal way to prove it :/

Comment: part b I did by myself eventually

Comment: succeeded :) thx